# Who is willing to trade with me?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I'm currently doing the *Trade Agreement* quest, which involves trading Miralife trading cards with residents of New LA. Unfortunately, this is one of the quests where the game doesn't help. NLA is a huge place with lots of people to talk to, so finding out who's willing to trade and in what order is a huge task.

Who is willing to trade with me, and in what order?

Answer (score 3):

The *Trade Agreement* quest begins by talking to the Nopon **Warawa** in the Commercial District (East Melville Street). She'll give you a *Bronze Blatta Card* to get started.

---

Trade the *Bronze Blatta Card* for a *Bronze Cinicula Card*. For that, you'll have to talk to **Liviana** in the Commercial District (East of North Founders Street), close to where Yelv usually hangs out.

Find the Nopon **Pirapira** in the Commercial District (East of West Melville Street, behind Pauline's "Restaurant Rosemoss" and Coco & Jo's "Ewen Lewis") next to some dumpsters. She'll trade her *Silver Mortifole Card* for your *Bronze Cinicula Card*. You'll also need **5 Coaletri** and **2 Meteo Eater**, both are Collectibles found in Primordia.

Your next trading partner is the Ma-non **Capsica** on the Ma-non Ship (Northeast of Starboard, upper level, eating Pizza at a table with a bunch of other Ma-non). She'll take your *Silver Mortifole Card* in exchange for... a *Ma-non Hunting Kit*?

Luckily, **Wilbur** in the Residential District (In the backyard of a villa Southwest of Ishmael Hills, in front of a swimming pool with his secretary Pepper) is willing to give you a *Silver Xiphias Card* in exchange for your newly acquired *Ma-non Hunting Kit*.

Finally, talk to the Orphean **Ton'barac** in the Residential District (Eastmost tennis court at the Sports Complex). He'll want your *Silver Xiphias Card* in exchange for the *Gold Nopopotamus Card* he just found.

---

With the *Gold Nopopotamus Card* finally in your grasp, it is time to return to Warawa and finish the quest. You may now congratulate yourself for successfully trading one of the most common Copper Blatta Cards for the legendary Gold Nopopotamus Card. Congratulations!